# Sorted Stack in Java

Tags: java, sorting, stack

I'm trying to implement a stack that keeps the items in a sorted manner and returns the least element in every pop. I'm using two stacks to implement the sorted stack.

Here's my implementation of the plain vanilla stack.

```
public class Stack<T> implements Iterable{
    private Node head;

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new StackIterator();
    }

    private class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>{
        private T data;
        private Node next;

        public Node(T data){
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
        }

        public int compareTo(T other){
            return data.compareTo(other);
        }
    }

    private class StackIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

        Node current = head;
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (current != null);
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            T item = (T) current.data;
            current = current.next;
            return item;
        }
    }

    public void push(T item){
        Node p = new Node((Comparable) item);
        if(head == null){
            head = p;
            return;
        }
        p.next = head;
        head = p;

    }
    public T pop(){
        if(head == null){
            System.out.println("Popping off an empty stack!!!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        T item = (T) head.data;
        head = head.next;
        return item;

    }
}
```

This stack is used in the SortedStack. Here's the partial code.

```
public class SortedStack<T> {

    private int size;
    private  Stack<T> s1;
    private Stack<T> s2;

    public SortedStack(){

        s1 = new Stack<>();
        s1 = new Stack<>();
        size = 0;
    }
    public void push(T item){

        for (Iterator<T> iter = s1.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); iter.next()){
            if (iter.compareTo(item) > 0){
               s2.push(s1.pop());
            }else if(iter.compareTo(item) < 0){
                s1.push(item);
                break;
            }else{
                s1.push(item);
                break;
            }
        }
        for (Iterator<T> iter = s2.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); iter.next()){
            s1.push(s2.pop());
        }
    }

    public T pop(){

    }


}
```

The problem is the T(Object) comparison of the nodes doesn't get resolved in the `SortedStack`. The `compareTo` doesn't work. This is understandably because of the fact that `Node` is an inner private class of `Stack`. My question is how can I expose the `compareTo` method of the `Node` class to the `SortedStack` for implementing it's logic without indiscriminately making everything public?

Comment: Why not use a List that you keep sorted? Why are you trying to call this a Stack?

Comment: How could you compare an Iterator with an item. (i.e., for example, an Iterator<Integer> with an Integer)? That doesn't make sense. Compare T with another T.

Comment: I think you're trying to implement a [Priority Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), to complement @Todd .

Answer (score 0):

You have many mistakes in your code.
For example, why are you trying to compare an iterator to an item?
Also,  the logic is broken: you compare an item being inserted to s1's head, and then push it to the tail.
As long as the first item inserted is the smallest of all, all the others will always end up in the  insertion order.
Consider inserting 0, then 3, then 1 for example.

To answer your question, you want your `extends Comparable<T>` type boundary on the `SortedStack`  declaration, not on `Node`. 
`Node` does not need to be `Comparable` at all.

If this is not for homework, just use `TreeSet`  instead.